# Identifier not found in this C++ code

Tags: c++

I have the following C++ code which gives me the following error:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    MyPrinter(100);
    MyPrinter(100.90);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

template <class T> 
void MyPrinter(T arr)
{
    cout<<"Value is:  " + arr;
}
```

[image]

What am I missing here ?

Comment: I think you're missing a declaration or a definition.

Comment: Oh, you edited and provided the code. That changes everything!

Comment: @Fanael Coming from C# world I forgot C++ is different...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use an identifier before you declare or define it.

Defining it before you use it would work:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T> 
void MyPrinter(T arr)
{
    cout<<"Value is:  " + arr;
}

int main()
{
    MyPrinter(100);
    MyPrinter(100.90);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just **declare** `MyPrinter` by putting the below code before `main` (and leave the rest of your code as is):

```
template <class T>
void MyPrinter(T arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

The template definition should be placed before its first use. You need to place the template definition above `main` :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Template Definition here
template <class T> 
void MyPrinter(T arr)
{
    cout<<"Value is:  " + arr;
}

int main()
{
    MyPrinter(100);
    MyPrinter(100.90);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Another way would be to use a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Forward Declaration
template <class T> void MyPrinter(T arr);


int main()
{
    MyPrinter(100);
    MyPrinter(100.90);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

template <class T> 
void MyPrinter(T arr)
{
    cout<<"Value is:  " + arr;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`MyPrinter` is not visible at the point you use it, since its declared and defined after that in the source code. You can make it work by either moving the definition of `MyPrinter` before of `main`:

```
template <class T> 
void MyPrinter(T arr)
{
    cout<<"Value is:  " + arr;
}

int main()
{
    MyPrinter(100);
    MyPrinter(100.90);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

or by forward declaring `MyPrinter`:

```
template <class T>
void MyPrinter(T arr);

int main()
{
    MyPrinter(100);
    MyPrinter(100.90);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

template <class T> 
void MyPrinter(T arr)
{
    cout<<"Value is:  " + arr;
}
```